# In Stripe Checkout, how do I set charge amount dynamically?

Tags: stripe-payments

This is from Stipe documentation, it charges $20.00. My question is, if I have an item charging $20.00, but I may also have an $5.00 addon item that user can choose by clicking a checkbox. So the charge amount could be $20 or $25. How can I implement that?

```
 <form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: You'd want to use the custom integration and set the amount via javascript: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: Do you mean here: `handler.open({
      name: 'Stripe.com',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: 2000
    });` The amount '2000' can be replaced with a variable?

Comment: yes that's what he means. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ra010dby/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the custom method instead of simple method by following reference page

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom